# Hiding a field in a node conditionally

Tags: theming, nodes

I have a field that's a term reference field. If it has a value 'x' I want it to show on the node page. However if it has the value 'y' I don't want it to show. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked the [Field formatter conditions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc) to see if it supports term references?

Comment: @Shawn Conn thanks again. This is an unusual module though. I can only choose to hide a field if 'some other field' has conditions...I can't seem to hide the field I want to hide if THAT field has the condition I want to use to hide itself.

Comment: Odd , conditionally formatting a field based on its value seems like a common use case. You might want to throw in a feature request to the maintainer if it hasn't been requested.

Comment: @Shawn Conn. I discovered others had complained about this. So I ended up hacking the module and changed line 145 in ffc.ffc_conditions_info.inc from 'TRUE' to 'FALSE'. That allowed me to use the same field for its own conditions. Fixed my problems. Thanks again sir!

Comment: Great! I added that as the answer if you want to tag that for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Field Formatter Conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc) module should do the trick. It's currently in beta and doesn't work on excluding fields based on their own value.

However, if you change function `ffc_get_condition_fields` on [line 145](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ffc/tree/ffc.ffc_conditions_info.inc?id=e56efc699aa26efb2a04654f732e9cf2ba62d88b#n145) in **ffc_conditions_info.inc** such that `$exclude_current_field` is `FALSE`.

```
function ffc_get_condition_fields($context, $exclude_current_field = FALSE) {
...
}
```

it will let you hide field display when it has a certain value.